# Express $\nabla \Delta u_t \cdot \nabla \Delta u$ with no Spatial Derivatives Applied to $u_t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, laplacian

Let $u \in \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R^3 \times (0, \infty); \mathbb R)$ be a smooth function mapping from three spatial dimensions and a positive value for time to the real numbers. $u_t$ shall denote the derivative of $u(\vec x, t)$ with respect to time. $\nabla$ and $\Delta$ shall denote the spatial gradient and Laplacian respectively. In the following, I suppress the arguments $(\vec x, t)$ to remove visual clutter.

I wish to expand the dot product
$$\nabla \Delta u_t \cdot \nabla \Delta u$$
so that $u_t$ is left by itself without a spatial derivative. I begin with the identity
$$\nabla \cdot (\Delta u_t \nabla \Delta u)=\nabla \Delta u_t\cdot \nabla\Delta u +\Delta u_t \Delta^2u$$
so that we have
$$\nabla \Delta u_t\cdot \nabla\Delta u=\nabla \cdot (\Delta u_t \nabla \Delta u)-\Delta u_t \Delta^2u$$

I have already found a way to cancel $\Delta u_t \Delta^2 u$ with another equation, but I am having difficulty expressing $\Delta u_t \nabla \Delta u$ in terms of $u_t$. Largely, my problem stems from the fact that $\nabla \Delta u$ is a vector valued quantity. I was wondering if  the Laplacian vector calculus identity
$$ \tilde \Delta \vec v = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec v) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec v)$$
applied to $\nabla u$ would yield a solution. Taking

$$ 
\begin{align}
\tilde \Delta \nabla u &= \nabla (\nabla \cdot \nabla u) + \nabla \times (\nabla \times u) \\
&= \nabla \Delta u + \nabla \times (\nabla \times \nabla u) \\
&= \nabla \Delta u
\end{align}
$$

and

$$ 
\begin{align}
\nabla \Delta u_t \cdot \nabla \Delta u &= \tilde \Delta \nabla u_t \cdot \tilde \Delta \nabla u
\end{align}
$$

Can I express the above quantity in terms of $\tilde \Delta (u_t \nabla u)$, $\Delta (u_t u)$, or something else of the form $\tilde \Delta (u_t D u)$ where $D$ is some spatial derivative operator?

Comment: What do you mean by $u_t$ with no spatial derivatives? Those spatial derivatives will always be there no matter what notation you use to represent them and they won't go away. If this was in an integral you could use integration by parts.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am trying to express the equations in such a fashion that they represent the condition of being divergence free (or incompressibility) for a vector field. For example, we have that $\nabla \cdot (u_t \nabla u) - \frac{1}{2}(|\nabla u|^2)_t = u_t \Delta u$. In the left-hand expression only $u_t$ instead of $\nabla u_t$ or $\Delta u_t$ occurs. I am trying to look for a way to produce an analogous formula for $\nabla \Delta u$, but I am unable to remove the term $\Delta u_t$.

Comment: But do you see how your example term was the difference of two derivative terms and the term in your question is one single term with nothing being subtracted off to allow canceling of the terms you don't want? What you're asking for is impossible or misunderstood

Comment: @NinadMunshi I filled up about a page and a half with algebra prior to this formula. I had everything cancel out to yield $u_t \Delta^3 u$; however, one of the original terms was written as $\nabla \cdot (\Delta u_t \nabla \Delta u)$. I had wanted to rewrite it such that the $\Delta u_t$ term could be replaced by other terms solely based on $u_t$. Could I send you my work in a chat?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to take a look